# Form in Bootbox Dialog

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I want to display a Bootbox dialog that includes an "OK" button. When the user clicks the "OK" button, it should POST back, with the ID of the message to confirm that the user has viewed the message. The Bootbox dialog is the form. I don't see a way to make the dialog buttons a submit form with hidden fields, which is what I assume is the right way to accomplish my goals.

Comment: Looks like the plugin has a prompt with a callback function. You could use that instead.

Comment: The last example from [this](http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html]) shows a way to use a form in a Bootbox dialog. Is that this kind of things you are looking for?

Comment: @IsabelInc - I'm taking a look at going that route

Comment: @Mistalis - It has a form, so that's close to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comments from [Isabel Inc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3649063/isabel-inc) and [Mistalis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4927984/mistalis), I have a working solution.

Notes specific to my implementation:

- The messages contain images that need to be responsive, so I add the appropriate Bootstrap classes to each image
- The messages may have links. Clicking a link is equivalent to clicking "OK" on the dialog

And the JavaScript that makes it happen...

```
jQuery(function($, window, bootbox, undefined) {
    var accept = function(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {message_id: 244826},
            success: callback()
        });
    };

    var $message = $('<p><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/80fa81938a6d1df92cd101d7fe997a71" alt></p><p>Here is a message from <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/244826/sonny">Sonny</a>.</p>');
    $message.find('img').addClass('img-responsive center-block');
    $message.find('a').on('click', function(e) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (0 === href.length) {
            return;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        accept(function() { window.location.href = href; });
    });

    bootbox.dialog({
        message: $message,
        closeButton: false,
        buttons: {
            accept: {
                label: 'OK',
                callback: function() {
                    accept(function() { window.location.reload(); });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}(jQuery, window, bootbox));
```